# IIS - Physical Path Wrong

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-10

I just upgraded from Win 7 to Win 10, and my IIS is now also v10. When browsing to my Web API on Win 7, it just worked. Now, on Win 10, I get a 404 NOT Found. I'm just hitting localhost. What I don't understand is why the physical path is different than what IIS shows, and why there are no contents in the physical path.

My physical path is this:
C:\DevFs\Apps\MultipleModuleAssembly\Components\Main\MmaComponents\Source\Server\MmaWebApi

[image]

Yet, when I browse and get the failure, I see this:

[image]

Why is the physical path in the users folder?
C:\Users\fs104679\Documents\My Web Sites\MmaWebClient-Site\MmaWebApi\api

When running the app, why is the physical path different than what I have set in IIS?

Comment: What does the configuration for your MmaWebClient site look like? Is it perhaps handling the request instead of this API site? (the path has ...WebClient... in it)?

Comment: The path of the client and the Web API are both "C:\DevFs..." and not "C:\Users..."

Comment: Is the path correct for the Default Web Site in IIS? Does it point to C:\DevFs?

Comment: The default web site has this: %SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot. It worked with that same setting on Win 7.

Comment: Interesting: If I browse to index.html in file explorer, and open it with IE, the site comes up. So it seems like IIS is not making the connection to the right path/file.

Comment: Did you get the solution for this? I am getting the same issue..

Comment: I did not. If you find an answer, it would be good to post here.

Answer (score 7):

Just encountered this exact issue.

Turns out we had a site running in IISExpress, also bound to port 80. This seemed to break our defaultwebsite in IIS. Stopping IISExpress fixed it for us.

Changed the port of the IISExpress site so it can't happen again.

Make sure your port mappings are correct everywhere.

Comment: You might check if IIS uses `*:80:` binding, while IIS Express uses `*:80:localhost`. If so, then IIS Express's binding takes precedence for requests at `http://localhost`, as host header matches.

Answer (score 4):

If using Visual Studios. There's a chance that the Physical Path is being stored in the ApplicationHost.config file under the .VS folder. Just go to the project site and change the path to the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

A virtual directory can have a WEB.CONFIG file with a redirect command. Thus, the URL points to a configured path and the WEB.CONFIG redirects you to another path.

Comment: +1 for the tip. I no longer have a way to verify if this is actually the case, but I don't think it is. Still, good information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, then checked web.config pdf path was http://localhost/myfolder then I converted it to https://mywebsiteURL/myfolder then baaaaannng. It resolved

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).