# Running an ASP.net project with an Application Pool with a specific Identity yields "(403) Forbidden"

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I'm getting this error message when trying to start an ASP.net project from Visual Studio (it doesn't run):

`Unable to start debugging on the web server. The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.`

[image]

`Help` takes me to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/error-the-web-server-is-not-configured-correctly) which is unhelpful. Searching for the more general error yields me [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/error-unable-to-start-debugging-on-the-web-server#specificerrors) which is also unhelpful. I'm using IIS 10 with an Application Pool of my creation with a different Identity than mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio, selecting `Debug > Start Without Debugging` gives me a webpage with a more useful error:

```
The current identity (username) does not have write access to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files'.
```

Navigating to that folder, right clicking `Temporary ASP.NET Files`, selecting `Properties`, `Security` tab, `Edit`, `Add`, and entering the Identity from my custom `Application Pool` solves this error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have changed `Solution Configuration` from `Release` to `Debug` mode.

[image: Release Mode]

To

[image: Debug Mode]

This solution may work for someone.

Answer (score 0):

for me the issue was physical path pointed to some other folder, and below post helped fixed the issue

[another site running on IISExpress](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55801463/9363343)